# error getMap() in android studio map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

**hello guys, please help me. I don't know what to do**

I have also done the suggestion that has been given `android studio`

[image]

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: Please post your code and logcat as a code.

Comment: Cast you Fragment with `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: Make sure that you have given permission in the manifest to access fine location/course location as you are setting MyLocationEnabled as true. Apart from this, you have to give runtime permission to access location.

Answer (score 1):

getMap() is deprecated. Use getMapAsync() like below.

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: where should I put this coding

Answer (score 0):

These both errors are different.

1. getmap() is deprecated. you have to use `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)`
2. `setMyLocationEnable` needs to check for run time permission of `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

**for issue 1 try this:**

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
    }
});
```

**For issue 2 use this**

```
if (googleMap != null) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: where should I put this coding. I've put using permission location in androidmanifest.xml but still error

Comment: Answer Updated please check